# What is a Service Model exactly in a project

Tags: java, service

We have been building an internal project management tool. My lead asked me to define the services for the project. The main entities we will be using in the project are:

1. Projects
2. Releases
3. Milestones
4. Resources

What i am unable to get is what exactly is a service? Service refers to Web services? Rest services? The functions I will be implementing for the entities?

And what is a good service model for a project? How do i measure if the service model is good or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Services in this case might mean a lot of things but I wouldn't count web services amongst them.

Take a look at BitBucket which is another project management tool consisting of version control, ticket/issue tracker, chat, resource system, code revision, wiki and probably other stuff I haven't bumped into yet.

By services in this case I understand features like e-mail notifications on issue update/comment.

But it might be worth while talking this over with your lead. You're right that you should be able to figure things out for yourself but he could at least set you on the right path for your research.